# Solidity's install_soc() function takes forever to finishe running

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

print("install start")

install_solc("v0.7.0")

print("install finish")

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
print(simple_storage_file)

print("finished downloading")
# Compile our solidity
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            },
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.7.0",
)

print("Here si the results")
print(compiled_sol)
```

For some reason, the code just continues to load at install_solc("v0.7.0") and doesn't move forward and print the following line "install finish". I have installed py-solc-x through conda because I am running python in conda environment. And the python is running 3.7.11

I am trying to understand why this infinite loading is happening. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This only happened to me the first time I ran `install_solc("0.6.0")`. I was impatient and kept quitting out as I thought something had gone wrong, but if you let it finish it will never have to do it again (at least for that version). Took about five minutes (!) for me.

By the way, I think `v0.7.0` is incorrect - you don't need to include the `v`.